# jQuery passing parameters to plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on my first jQuery plugin, and have some troubles with passing 0 as a parameter.

What I want to do is to set `element.eq(parameter)` and this works just fine with 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on, but 0 won't work. It works if I type in `element.eq(0)`.

My `console.log` outputs:

```
0
null x2
```

I have a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RubberPoint/mdqg1rxp/) with the problem

So how would I go about to make it show first child?

```
$.fn.miobi.defaultOptions = {
        page: null,
        pageActive: null
    };

$('body').miobi({
    page: '.page',
    pageActive: 1 // not working with 0
});
```

Comment: I know it outputs 0, but its not showing element 0 = first-child

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `0` is a falsey value, so rather than testing if it's truthy (it isn't), explicitly check for it being not-undefined:

```
if (typeof options.pageActive !== 'undefined') {
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mdqg1rxp/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go

http://jsfiddle.net/Phatjam98/gqg8qnqm/

So your if is throwing false because 0 is falsey in JS.  So change:

```
if(options.pageActive){
```

To:

```
if(options.pageActive !== undefined){
```